# Change a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn into DataGridViewComboBoxClolumn in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in my Windows Form, and it has a column which can be edited by the User. I need it to be a ComboboxColumn. It has already some data, so not every cell is empty...The Column is created in the designer... How can I still change the ColumnType, and how do I add Items to the ComboBoxes?

Comment: Sounds like you want an editable combobox column, where users can add new items by typing directly into the column? I'm just heading out so don't have time to answer, but it is explained in the DataGridView FAQ http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=datagridview%20faq&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CGMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwindowsclient.net%2FSamples%2FGo%2520To%2520Market%2FDataGridView%2FDataGridView%2520FAQ.doc&ei=j8OwT-3jA8zcsgaiqvGUBA&usg=AFQjCNFxVe3EWtsJNP7xXxENGfV6dxU0EQ  if you are still having trouble just comment here. If you solve it yourself, post an answer

Comment: Thank you I will try it out and post my results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left it a TextBoxColumn, the User edits it in an other way